# How to parse and put together pieces of text from an XML response Java

Tags: java, regex, xml, xpath

I have the following XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <MetaData>
        <xpath>/Temporary/EIC/HaveInaccurateInfo</xpath>
        <enumeration>AtLeastOneConditionTrue</enumeration>
        <scenario>TRUE_BECAUSE_OF_ONE_CONDITION</scenario>
        <Template>
            <Text id="1">You don't qualify because </Text>
            <PertinentDataInputNodeNameListInline id="2"
                >ApplicableConditions</PertinentDataInputNodeNameListInline>
            <Text id="3">.</Text>
        </Template>
    </MetaData>

    <MetaData>
        <xpath>/Temporary/EIC/DisqualifiedBecauseAllQualifyingChildrenHaveITIN</xpath>
        <scenario>DISQUALIFIED</scenario>
        <Template>
           <Text id="1">Your eligibility for this credit is not affected since </Text>
           <PertinentDataInputNodeNameListInline id="2">ApplicableConditions</PertinentDataInputNodeNameListInline>
           <Text id="3">.</Text>
        </Template>
    </MetaData>
</data>
```

I'd like to be able to write some java class to be able to combine/construct the text nodes under the `Template` node, when I pass in an `xpath` and `scenario` (that way we'll know which Template to use).

**Example:**

```
public String constructSentence(String xpath, String scenario) {
    // some processing here

    return constructedSentence;
}
```

**output:**

> You don't qualify because ApplicableConditions.

etc...

How can I accomplish this using Java? What is the best approach? Any recommendations? I've heard many many times using regex to parse xml would be a sin, I'm a noob so any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

Okay I've got something here but it seems I am building incomplete sentence along with complete sentences.

```
String h = new String();
List<String> sent = new ArrayList<>();
Document doc = getDocumentXML(xml);
doc.normalize();
System.out.println("Root node: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Template");

for (int tmp = 0; tmp < nList.getLength(); tmp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(tmp);

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        NodeList nl = nNode.getChildNodes();

        for(int j=0; j<nl.getLength(); j++) {
            Node node = nl.item(j);

            if(nl.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element e = (Element) node;

                if( e.hasAttribute("id") ) {

                    String nameNode = e.getNodeName();

                    System.out.println("GetNodeName: "+nameNode);

                    Integer currentAttrNum = Integer.parseInt( e.getAttribute("id") );
                    h += e.getTextContent();
                    System.out.println("Current id num: "+currentAttrNum);

                    if(e.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && !e.getNextSibling().hasAttributes()) {
                        System.out.println("last sibling");
                        sent.add( h );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(String s : sent) {
            System.out.println("Sentence: "+s);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following output in my foreach loop:

```
Sentence: You don't qualify because 
Sentence: You don't qualify because ApplicableConditions
Sentence: You don't qualify because ApplicableConditions.
Sentence: You don't qualify because ApplicableConditions.Your eligibility for this credit is not affected since 
Sentence: You don't qualify because ApplicableConditions.Your eligibility for this credit is not affected since ApplicableConditions
Sentence: You don't qualify because ApplicableConditions.Your eligibility for this credit is not affected since ApplicableConditions.
```

I should only have:

```
Sentence: You don't qualify because ApplicableConditions.
Sentence: Your eligibility for this credit is not affected since ApplicableConditions.
```

Can you find the bug in my code?

Comment: You can use an xml parser and carry out a normal logic with it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about XML (and by much I mean nothing at all) but I'll try to help. If you get a text output you can `return` in Java, you can take that text and do something along the lines of

```
/*regexNameHere is the name you give the array, inputTextVar is the variable 
*(make sure it's a string!) assigned to the text you receive from the XML process
*/
String [] (regexNameHere) = (inputTextVar).split("character to split by");
//This is what you use to declare variables...
String var1 = regexNameHere[0];
String var2 = regexNameHere[1];
```

And so on. If the variable `regexNameHere` was equal to the string "Regex split string" and the `.split` argument is `(" ")` (a space) then `regexNameHere[0]` would equal "Regex", the `regexNameHere[1]` would be "split" and `regexNameHere[2]` would be "string".

If you want to split something like the "ApplicableConditions" in your text, I would imagine you just put "Applicable" as the `.split` argument, and `regexNameHere[0]` would equal "Applicable" and `regexNameHere[1]` would be equal to "Conditions."

Hope this helped, and good luck!