# Split numerical list of String

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of `String` and doesn't have a skills in regex. So I need your help.

First String :

```
[begin]
65. This tutorial walks you through a series of exercises to get familiar with Kotlin. 
66. Kotlin Koans are a series of exercises to get you familiar with the Kotlin Syntax.
67. Each exercise is created as a failing unit test and your job is to make it pass. You can play with Koans online or offline by cloning the project on GitHub:
...
[end]
```

Second String

```
[begin]
63. Download the Koans by cloning the project from GitHub
64. Open up the project in IntelliJ IDEA or your favorite editor. Note: If IntelliJ IDEA prompts you to update the Kotlin library, just click yes.
[end]
```

And other Strings...

#### Goal :

I need extract each numerical line as `String` :

```
String#1 : 63. Download the Koans by cloning the project from GitHub
String#2 : 64. Open up the project in IntelliJ IDEA or your favorite editor. Note: If IntelliJ IDEA prompts you to update the Kotlin library, just click yes.
String#3 : 65. This tutorial walks you through a series of exercises to get familiar with Kotlin. 
String#4 : 66. Kotlin Koans are a series of exercises to get you familiar with the Kotlin Syntax.
String#5 : 67. Each exercise is created as a failing unit test and your job is to make it pass. You can play with Koans online or offline by cloning the project on GitHub:
```

P.S. Will be VERY grateful to any online training tools for skill-up regex.

Comment: Literally just google "regex" and you will find all the tools you need.

Comment: @AlexHall I suppose it will be the very easy way :) Heroes doesn't look easy ways :D

Comment: What does "Heroes doesn't look easy ways :D" even mean? Heroes would probably use the necessary resources to complete something which you refuse to do.

Comment: Something like so? https://regex101.com/r/fZ9lV1/1

Comment: ssh, i'm confused. are you wanting to reorder by line number?

Comment: True heroes ask other people to do their work and solve their problems for them with no effort on their end.  God bless these valiant souls.

Comment: He just wants to extract line numbers

Comment: @sweaver2112 actually yes, but for reorder I will use different mechanism. The question only about extract strings.

Comment: @cricket_007 put your answer as separated answer. I will accept.

Comment: For Java, I gave [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851260/how-to-parse-and-put-together-pieces-of-text-from-an-xml-response-java/36851670#36851670) about regex a while ago, perhaps you can take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works for javascript
`/^(\d+)/gm`

https://regex101.com/r/fZ9lV1/1

Answer (score 2):

I will go this way:

1. Define a class to parse lines and text.. (you will need that to sort the final `List`)

   ```
   class TextLine implements Comparable<TextLine> {

       private int line;
       private String lineText;

       public TextLine(int line, String lineText) {
           this.line = line;
           this.lineText = lineText;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "String:" + line + lineText;
       }

       @Override
       public int compareTo(TextLine o) {
           return Integer.compare(this.line, o.line);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Read and parse all the lines you find in a `List` (you are right, regex is one way to get it)
3. Sort the list using `Collections.sort`...
4. Print

**Example:**

```
public class TestApp {

    private List<TextLine> output = new ArrayList<TextLine>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestApp tt = new TestApp();
        String str = "65. This tutorial walks you through a series of exercises to get familiar with Kotlin. ";
        tt.populateLsit(str);
        str = "67. Each exercise is created as a failing unit test and your job is to make it pass. You can play with Koans online or offline by cloning the project on GitHub:";
        tt.populateLsit(str);
        str = "66. Kotlin Koans are a series of exercises to get you familiar with the Kotlin Syntax. ";
        tt.populateLsit(str);
        str = "63. Download the Koans by cloning the project from GitHub";
        tt.populateLsit(str);
        str = "64. Open up the project in IntelliJ IDEA or your favorite editor. Note: If IntelliJ IDEA prompts you to update the Kotlin library, just click yes.";
        tt.populateLsit(str);
        tt.sortPrint();
    }

    private void sortPrint() {
        Collections.sort(output);
        System.out.println(output);

    }

    private void populateLsit(String str) {
        Matcher match = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)|(.*)").matcher(str);
        // String r = match.group();
        match.find();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(match.group());
        match.find();
        String s = match.group();
        output.add(new TextLine(i, s));
    }
}
```

---

[Here is a good starting point for regex](http://regexone.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I expect your regexp should looks like following `^(\d+.*)`
where

```
^ - start of line
\d+ - any non zero amount of numbers
.*  - any symbols
( ) - grouping
```

You can play with it on: rubular.com